# Select count / duplicates

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table with all U.S. zip codes. each row contains the city and state name for the zip code. I'm trying to get a list of cities that show up in multiple states. This wouldn't be a problem if there weren't X amount of zip codes in the same city...

So basically, I just want to the city in a state to count as 1 instead of it counting the city/state 7 times because there are 2+ zip codes in that city/state...

I'm not really sure how to do this. I know I need to use count but how do I tell the mysql to only count a given city/state combo as 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT City, Count(City) As theCount
FROM (Select City, State From tblCityStateZips Group By City, State) As C
GROUP By City
HAVING COUNT Count(City) > 1
```

This would return all cities, with count, that were contained in more than one state.

Greenville        39
Greenwood          2
GreenBriar         3
etc.

Answer (score 4):

First group on state and city, then group the result on city:

```
select City
from (
  select State, City
  from ZipCode
  group by State, City
) x
group by City
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This was almost it! Just needed to change the first line to: SELECT city, COUNT(city) as c

Comment: @mike: So you wanted how many states each city shows up in also? That wasn't in the question, so I didn't include it in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Will this do the trick

```
Select CityName, Count (Distinct State) as StateCount
From CityStateTable
Group by CityName
HAVING Count (Distinct State) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a select distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, state FROM table GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have created a separate table for zip codes then to avoid the duplication.

You want to look into the [GROUP BY Aggregate.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html)