# Counting rows with 2 duplicate/matching columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I tried the best answer here: [Select count / duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516546/select-count-duplicates)
And didn't get accurate results, maybe because this example is for one field?

I tried this originally, and didn't seem to work either:

```
   SELECT T.STATE, T.CITY, COUNT(T2.CITY)
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T.STATE, T.CITY 
             FROM TABLE ) T
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 ON T2.STATE = T.STATE 
                  AND T2.CITY = T.CITY
 GROUP BY T.STATE, T.CITY
```

This gives inaccurate results as well.  I'm trying to get the count of duplicate values of 2 fields in a table.

Sample Data:

```
 Los Angeles, CA, Bob
 New York, NY, Bill
 Los Angeles, CA, Jim
 Los Angeles, CA, Joe
 New York, NY, Gary
 Los Angeles, CA, Roger
```

Should Return:

```
 Los Angeles, CA, 4
 New York, NY, 2
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
    CITY VARCHAR(100),
    [STATE] CHAR(2),
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
 ('Los Angeles', 'CA', 'Bob'),
 ('New York', 'NY', 'Bill'),
 ('Los Angeles', 'CA', 'Jim'),
 ('Los Angeles', 'CA', 'Joe'),
 ('New York', 'NY', 'Gary'),
 ('Los Angeles', 'CA', 'Roger')

 SELECT CITY,[STATE],COUNT(*) [COUNT]
 FROM @TABLE
 GROUP BY CITY,[STATE]
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1


 --if there are erroneous white spaces and inconsistant case, and collation is case sensitive use this
 DELETE FROM @TABLE
 INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
 ('  Los Angeles', 'CA', 'Bob'),
 ('New York', 'NY', 'Bill'),
 ('Los ANgeles   ', 'CA', 'Jim'),
 ('LOS Angeles', 'CA', 'Joe'),
 ('New YorK  ', 'NY', 'Gary'),
 ('  Los Angeles ', 'CA', 'Roger')

 SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(CITY))) [CITY] ,RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER([STATE]))) [STATE],COUNT(*) [COUNT]
 FROM @TABLE
 GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(CITY))),RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER([STATE])))
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to get all records that have a count > 1.

```
select T.State, T.City, COUNT(1)
FROM TABLE T
GROUP BY T.State, T.City
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: This returns everything with a count of 1, thats not what it should be.

Comment: Are you sure? The HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 should mean only return when the count is greater that 1. Are you sure you got the having right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.STATE, T.CITY, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Table X T
GROUP BY T.STATE, T.CITY
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

If input is not accurate , you can try

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(T.STATE)), LTRIM(RTRIM(T.CITY)), COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Table X T
GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM(T.STATE)), LTRIM(RTRIM(T.CITY))
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: This returns everything with a count of 1, thats not what it should be.